# 2 gamers 1 PC steam issues

Tags: steam, multiseat

So I use a multiseat program called Aster v7.

This program allows two (or more but two in my case) separate windows users (e.g admin and guest, or user1 and user2) to log into windows.

No screen sharing, no virtualization, no i/o conflicts each user has his own screen with its own boundaries his own mouse and keyboard and input of e.g keyboard 1(from user 1) doesnt show up on user2 screen and vise versa same with sound and executing programs (if user 1 executes a program it pops on user1's desktop/screen not on user2's desktop/screen)

Also both users have their own IP.

But they run on the same windows OS isntallation and share resources such as ram CPU etc **dynamically** (so no hard lock e.g sharing half cores for one user and the other half to the 2nd user)

Both users can play **stand alone games** just fine  even play multiplayer maps with each other (as lan games if the game provides such an option) even if we use 1 graphics card! (yet particularly in my case each user has his own graphics card)  each user just fires up his own instance of the game and no issues after that.

The only problem is with steam!  We have two different steam accounts (e.g steamuserA and steamuserB)

Each user has his own library of games (separately bought licenses for each individual account no family sharing)

But unfortunately even when installing steam twice (e.g c:/steam1 and D:/steam2 ) for each windows user steam doesnt boot for both users simultaneously!

Sometimes it does but even if it does only one user can play a game (the first user that manages to launch a game) the other user simply cant do anything after that.

**So how does steam know it runs on the same windows OS? since IPs are different?**

In other words I am asking could I edit some file (hosts maybe? or some steam file? or a registry key? ) to make it so that both steamusers be able to launch a steam game?

If one **windows user** launches steam (as steamuserA) and plays a game then the **2nd windows user** can play a standalone game with no issues the 2nd **windows user** just cant log into his seperate steam account(as steamuserB).

Comment: Probably have to run one of the steams in sandboxie. Give that a shot

Comment: well I think it doesnt work anymore but even then this wouldn't solve much since the other user could only play offline games. There must be a way (since we have two separate Windows users, two separate steam users, two separate IPs, two separate game file source directories and two separate game licenses for each game) to make this work.